# State machine radio buttons

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-msm

How can I implement radio buttons in [boost meta state machine](http://www.boost.org/libs/msm/index.html)?
The problem is the amount of transitions grows quadratically, e.g. with 3 buttons the options are:

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 1
2 -> 3
3 -> 1
3 -> 2
```

But with 4 buttons the options are:

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
2 -> 1
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
3 -> 1
3 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 1
4 -> 2
4 -> 3
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
{2, 3, 4} -> 1
{1, 3, 4} -> 2
{1, 2, 4} -> 3
{1, 2, 3} -> 4
```

in boost meta state machine?

Comment: Why would you _want_ to do this? Each state can go to any other state. At which point, there's no state machine. A state machine exists to provide a _restriction_ on which states have valid transitions to other states. You want any state to be able to go to any other. So what do you gain by using a state machine?